# Modifying a MySQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, database-trigger

I have a MySQL trigger that I would like to be modified. The only changes are in the trigger body.

Will updating the `ACTION_STATEMENT` Column in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS` suffice? Is this the right way to update a trigger? Specifically, I am looking for any problems that might arise by doing this.

Answer (score 2):

That won't work.

You need to drop the trigger and recreate it.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: Is that still applicable nowadays that mysql is 5.6/5.7/8.0? I don't see any warning about edition `information_schema.TRIGGERS` in the link (tho it's now 8.0 and 5.1 is no longer online apparently)

Comment: @Xenos I don't think this has changed in newer versions. As of MySQL 8.0 you still need to DROP/CREATE a trigger if you want to change it.

Comment: Indeed, I tried that after posting the comment, and the `TRIGGERS` table is not actually update-able (table cannot be updated or so). Hence the need of dropping and creating the trigger again.

Answer (score 1):

Download dbForge express (is free as in Beer).
Connect with that and edit the trigger.

Download page
http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/download.html

Direct link
[https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/dbforgemysql80exp.exe](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/dbforgemysqlfree.exe)

Don't muck about in the information_schema.
Oh and don't use MySQL workbench 5.2 I've had that one eat my work twice (..gone..) never again.

*No I don't have shares, just a happy dbForge user*

Comment: Thanks for recommendations!
 The correct link is https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/dbforgemysql80exp.exe

Comment: It would be far better to propose the statements to use, and eventually suggest a GUI editor that does it, rather than promoting an SQL client just because you like it.

Answer (score 0):

> The ACTION_STATEMENT column contains the statement to be executed when the trigger is invoked. This is the same as the text displayed in the Statement column of the output from SHOW TRIGGERS. Note that this text uses UTF-8 encoding.
>   [MYSQL TRIGGERS SCHEMA TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers-table.html)

You're right, if you edit the ACTION_STATEMENT field, you modify the SQL action.